# How write newly inserted data in datastore to storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

Iam trying to find a solution on how link datastore to a bucket.
In the shell i 've already wrote the command we can find in the doc :
"gcloud datastore export.... "
But i can't find a way to make it write the datastore inserted data into the storage bucket.
Thanks

Comment: Export just copies the data (e.g. for backups) to Cloud Storage. It does not keep the two (datastore -> storage) in sync. If you switch from Datastore to the new Firestore (which is in beta), then you can create a Cloud Function on Firestore events. This will require creating a new project and then migrating your data.

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley. So how can we trigger an automatic copy of the inserted datastore data into storage? I have to deal with datastore at the meantime at work. Firestore is for a near future hopefully

Comment: Datastore does not have event triggers.

Comment: Ok i understand @John Hanley. Thanks. I heard about cron. Can we at least use a cron to pick up the last inserted datas in order to copy them? (the purpose of that it's to trigger a storage function which works well with storage create event)

Comment: You can do just about anything you want outside of Datastore. Keep in mind that scanning has API and data charges. If one of your indexes is an insertion date field that will make it easier otherwise you will need to create a strategy for what is old and what is new.